# What is the difference between "origin date" and "departure date"?

Tags: terminology, time

In different sources e.g. [OAG's](https://www.oag.com) [API:s (Application Programming Interface)](https://xml.flightview.com/doc/json/), there are both (scheduled) "departure date" and "origin/origination date". In general (so not specifically OAG's API) is there a technical difference between these two or are they synonyms? Correlated, does the same apply to "destination" and "arrival"?

Comment: The definitions are probably in [Amadeus documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeus_CRS), as [OAG uses MIDT](https://www.oag.com/hubfs/User%20Guides/Traffic%20Analyser/TA-Main-Guide-July2017.pdf) data ([now Market Insights](https://www.amadeus-hospitality.com/amadeus-market-insights/)). That's more a travel.se question, or better a SO question.

Comment: Context and acronym definition are always nice to include.  For instance, does OAG = Aircraft On Ground, and API = Aviation Preflight Instruction?